# Adding and subtracting multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 columns in a table, all the columns hold numeric values.

I want to add column a and b and minus column c what would the SQL for that be?

Comment: You're not providing any information to go on here. Please edit your question and provide your table structure, a few rows of sample data, and  the desired output from that data. We don't know what you're trying to do, and can't see your screen or read your mind from here. Thanks.

Comment: @ElVieejo, since PL/SQL is specifically Oracle, it's probably the RDBMS. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am missing something, it sounds like you just need to do this:

```
select (NVL(cola, 0) + NVL(colb, 0)) - NVL(colc, 0)
from yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks, also if in case column a has total of B and c, how do i take out only c values form column A and keep value of B

Comment: @user803860 I am not sure I understand your question, can you clarify?

Comment: @bluefeet - the OP said nothing about desired behavior in one field or the other is NULL.  As such, I think your original posting was more correct.

Comment: I have a table with 3 fields A B C,
column  A has total number of calls
column  B has total number of dropped calls
column  C has total number of hang ups

Column A is Sum of B AND C

My goal is to get SUM of A and B Minus C, 

So i need grand total of calls

Database:- ORACLE

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the question you posed in your comment to @bluefeet's answer:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN A = B + C THEN A - C
         ELSE A + B - C
       END AS RESULT_VAL
  FROM SOME_TABLE
```

or you could just simply return B in the first case:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN A = B + C THEN B
         ELSE A + B - C
       END AS RESULT_VAL
  FROM SOME_TABLE
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also how about the qry below :                  select SUM ((A + B)-  C) calls from table

this gives me total sum of columns

Comment: Try `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN A = B + C THEN B ELSE A + B - C END) AS RESULT_SUM FROM SOME_TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below logic to subtract, implement the same using addition of multiple columns

```
select 
SUM(a.COL1 -       B.COL1) COL1,
SUM(a.COL2 -       B.COL2) COL2,
SUM(a.COL3 -  B.COL3) COL3,
SUM(a.COL4 - B.COL4) COL4,
SUM(a.COL5 -       B.COL5) COL5 ,
SUM(a.COL6 -       B.COL6) COL6,
SUM(a.COL7-    B.COL7) COL7
FROM 
(select Coln, --Common column
sum(COL1) COL1 ,
sum(COL2)  COL2,
sum(COL3) COL3,
sum(COL4) COL4,
sum(COL5) COL5,
sum(COL6) COL6,
sum(COL7) COL7
from wrk_prod
GROUP BY Coln) a,
(select Coln, --Common column
sum(COL1) COL1 ,
sum(COL2)  COL2,
sum(COL3) COL3,
sum(COL4) COL4,
sum(COL5) COL5,
sum(COL6) COL6,
sum(COL7) COL7
from wrk_test
GROUP BY Coln) b
where a.Coln = b.Coln;
```

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question